# Lightbox window darkening content in only Chrome after closing

Tags: css, google-chrome

I recently created my own custom lightbox for my site. It seems to be working fine, except for one really weird issue in Chrome. It causes the content being overlayed to become slightly more dim *after closing out of it*. Compare it against firefox or IE, you'll see a difference. Any ideas on what's causing the behaviour? I disabled foggy.js and it doesn't seem to stop it, it appears to be something with the CSS, but I can't figure out what is causing it. My javascript hides the whole darkening layer and popup. I have a second non-live version where the popup only runs once per session, when I refresh the page, the thumbnails are brighter. After manually opening and closing the popup, they become dim again.

http://chrisnuzzaco.com/testdesigns/promo-gallery-2.html

Below is the lightbox CSS:

```
#promoboxoverlay{
position:fixed;
z-index:100;
top:60px;
bottom:45px;
left:0px;
right:0px;
background-color:black;
opacity:0.65;
filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}


#wrapperwrapper{
left:0px;
right:0px;
top:60px;
bottom:45px;
position:fixed;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:325;

}

#promoboxwrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index:350;
  position: relative;

top:0px;
bottom:0px;
  text-align: center;
}
#promoboxwrapper:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em;

}


#promoboxcontent {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  position:relative;
  width:60%;
  height:auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* IE7 */
   *display: block;
   *margin-top: expression(this.offsetHeight < this.parentNode.offsetHeight ? parseInt((this.parentNode.offsetHeight - this.offsetHeight) / 2) + "px" : "0");


-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
 border-radius:5px;
 margin:5px;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 6em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);    
-moz-box-shadow:0 0 6em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
box-shadow:0 0 6em rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
border:0px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); 

}

#videotext{position:relative;  width:100%; z-index:200; }

#videotext img{width:100%; height:auto; display: block; z-index:200;}

#videotextinner{position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:45%; height:100%; color:#565656; padding-left:20px; font-family:lato; }

#close{position:absolute; top:-40px; right:-40px; z-index:500;}

#close img{width:40px; height:auto;}

#play{}

#play img{width:40%; height:auto; margin:0 auto; padding-top:10%;}

#videocontainer{position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:199; width:100%; max-height:100%; }

#videocontainer iframe {display: block;}

#openwrapper{position:fixed; bottom:45px; width:100%; z-index:200; text-align: center;}

#open{position:relative; bottom:0px; text-align: center; display:inline-block; height:30px; width:auto; background-color:#890000; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:5px; font-family:lato; font-size:1.25em; border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px; border-top-right-radius:5px 5px; -moz border-top-left-radius: 5px 5px; -moz border-top-right-radius:5px 5px; color:#dadada; box-shadow: 0px 0px 45px #000000; }
```

Below is the lightbox HTML:

```
<div id="wrapperwrapper">

<div id="promoboxoverlay"></div><!-- end promoboxoverlay div -->

<div id="promoboxwrapper">
<div id="promoboxcontent" >

  <div id="close" ><img src="close.png"/></div><!-- end close div -->


    <div id="videocontainer" class="video">

        <div id="videotext" ><a class="introVid" href="#video"><img src="headshot.jpg"></img>
            <div id="videotextinner"> <div>Hey John,</div> <div>I made a gallery and video</div> <div>just for you</div><div id="play"><img src="play.png"/></div> </div><!-- end videotextinner div --></a>
            </div><!-- end videotext div -->

    </div><!-- end videocontainer -->

</div><!-- end promoboxcontent div -->
</div><!-- end promoboxowrapper div -->
</div><!-- end wrapperwrapper div -->
```

Comment: Nope, it's because of Foggy. Foggy sets opacity: 0.8; on #pagewrapper3.

Comment: try to add opacity: 1 in your Foggy init code at the top of the page.

Comment: That was it! How did you find that? I searched for opacity:0.8 and can't find it. I just added $("#pagewrapper3").css({"opacity":"1"}); to the javascript for closing the overlay. Seems to work fine now in chrome.

Comment: Great! I've saw in inspector that #pagewrapper3 have set opacity to 0.8 after closing, and that is set inline. So, must be some JS code inserts that property, and then I've searched inside foggy js code and find it - there is opacity set to 0.8 by default. Foggy have option to set opacity manually on init, look here http://nbartlomiej.github.io/foggy/

Comment: Just found it in the code and fixed it. You wouldn't happen to understand how to make the foggy script not force a scroll back to the top of the page would you? It's a minor detail I'm willing to forgo, but kinda annoys me a bit.

Comment: Do you have some page where I can see that? I've never used Foggy, actually.

Comment: The original page linked up at the top of the post exhibits the behaviour. Just close the lightbox, scroll down, then click the red "hey john" button at the bottom of the page to re-open. It'll jump back to the top.